# How to save CSV file from MySQL Query in PHP, on server

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export-to-csv

I have a domain on Bluehost and need a PHP script which will execute a SQL select and export the data to a CSV file which is saved in some folder on the server. Here is what I tried in PHP:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTHNAME(date) = '$month' AND YEAR(date) = '$year' AND uid = '$uid' INTO OUTFILE 'test.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");
```

This was my first attempt but I keep getting permission errors with the folder I am trying to save the file into....which is in www/folder/subfolder

My second attempt is this:

```
$output = fopen('http://server.com/folder/subfolder/test.csv', 'w+');

fputcsv($output, array('tripid','startingLoc','endingLoc'));

$rows = mysql_query('SELECT tripid, startingLoc, endingLoc FROM autoTracker_trips');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output,$row);
```

I get the following errors:

```
[09-Mar-2014 12:43:38 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  fopen(http://server.com/folder/subfolder/test.csv): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in /home4/geronim9/public_html/folder/subfolder/export_csv.php on line 35
[09-Mar-2014 12:43:38 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  fputcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home4/geronim9/public_html/folder/subfolder/export_csv.php on line 37
```

So my question is, where on the server is a good place to save the CSV file...where am I allowed to save from PHP, and which of the two approaches is recommended

Note: above both examples of code above I have the connection info, I just didn`t want to post that.

Thank you!

Comment: file path not website url!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to use server path and not http path for the function [**`fopen()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to work correctly so change to

```
/your/path/folder/subfolder/test.csv
```

Otherwise you will need to activate [**`allow_url_fopen`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) in your php.ini

Answer (score 1):

Try this :
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');